# AWS S3 script to get versions of object & folder with same name (Version Enabled Bucket)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS Cloudshell to execute simple python script to fetch the all versionIds with following hierarchy.

```
AWS S3 > buckets >
  my-bucket >
    test_001
        KpJEgbcnjMr5QLzOkA2CfG5NMzPBvyqK
    test_001/
        my-obj
           4RektV43Cf.HK17BTyVpDVtFSQiLr.yf
           HGKVjaVDoPbdPyl2xKN5f0eDYjt69Jt1
           IWuZ62icRmaV7Qz7_TQlpxXaZeY1COyk
           rNTACJqaJVbudBB70XkjDssGDbFTAOe6
```

When I am doing this way

```
import boto3

AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'
AWS_PROFILE = 'default'

session = boto3.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE, region_name=AWS_REGION)
s3_client = session.client('s3')

class StopExecution(Exception):
    pass

def getVersions(bucket_name, object_key):
    versions_response = s3_client.list_object_versions(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=object_key, KeyMarker=object_key)
    versions = versions_response.get('Versions', [])
    version_ids = [version['VersionId'] for version in versions]
    print(f"VersionIds: {version_ids}")


bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
# Iterate over each bucket and copy its objects and versions to the destination bucket
try:
    print(f"Processing bucket: {bucket_name}")
    # List all objects in the bucket
    objects_response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)
    object_keys = [obj['Key'] for obj in objects_response.get('Contents', [])]
    object_keys_size = len(object_keys)
    print(f"Total {object_keys_size} no. of keys found in bucket: '{bucket_name}'")

    # Iterate over each object key and copy its versions to the destination bucket
    for object_key in object_keys:
        try:
            print("-----------------------------------------------------")
            print(f"Processing object: {object_key}")
            print("-----------------------------------------------------")
            getVersions(bucket_name, object_key)
            print("-----------------------------------------------------END_OF_COPY_ITERATION")
        except StopExecution as e:
            print("Execution stopped due to an error", e)
            break  # Exit the inner loop if an error occurs
except StopExecution as e:
    print("Execution stopped due to an error external loop:", e)
```

This above print statement giving me all versions, expecting individual key & folder should be differenciated.

output is

```
VersionIds: [KpJEgbcnjMr5QLzOkA2CfG5NMzPBvyqK, rNTACJqaJVbudBB70XkjDssGDbFTAOe6, 4RektV43Cf.HK17BTyVpDVtFSQiLr.yf]
```

***Expecting for test_001 object***

```
VersionIds: [KpJEgbcnjMr5QLzOkA2CfG5NMzPBvyqK]
```

***Expecting for test_001 folder***

```
VersionIds: [rNTACJqaJVbudBB70XkjDssGDbFTAOe6, 4RektV43Cf.HK17BTyVpDVtFSQiLr.yf]
```

actual output:

```
Processing bucket: my-bucket
Total 2 no. of keys found in bucket: 'my-bucket'
-----------------------------------------------------
Processing object: test_001
-----------------------------------------------------
VersionIds: ['4RektV43Cf.HK17BTyVpDVtFSQiLr.yf', 'HGKVjaVDoPbdPyl2xKN5f0eDYjt69Jt1', 'IWuZ62icRmaV7Qz7_TQlpxXaZeY1COyk', 'rNTACJqaJVbudBB70XkjDssGDbFTAOe6']
-----------------------------------------------------END_OF_COPY_ITERATION
-----------------------------------------------------
Processing object: test_001/my-obj
-----------------------------------------------------
VersionIds: []
-----------------------------------------------------END_OF_COPY_ITERATION
```

Not sure how can I restrict on `list_object_versions` method to be a specific response.

Answer (score 0):

if the keys start with a slash, you could consider those folders. Let me know if this does not work

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE, region_name=AWS_REGION)
s3_client = session.client('s3')

bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
object_key = 'your-object-key'

versions_response = s3_client.list_object_versions(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=object_key)

version_ids_folder = []
version_ids_key = []

for version in versions_response['Versions']:
    key = version['Key']
    if key.startswith('/'):  # Check for folder (key starts with slash)
        version_ids_folder.append(version['VersionId'])
    else:
        version_ids_key.append(version['VersionId'])

print(f"VersionIds for folder: {version_ids_folder}")
print(f"VersionIds for key: {version_ids_key}")
```

Comment: Certainly this wont helping, in nutshell the issue is for first iteration the expecting `test_001` file object should process instead in logs it is printing values of `test_001/` which is folder. and simply skipping `test_001` file object. only considering folder type

Comment: ok, are you using prefix and keyMarker correctly?
    versions_response = s3_client.list_object_versions(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=object_key, KeyMarker=object_key)

Comment: try

versions = s3_client.list_objects_versions(Bucket="mybucket",Prefix="test_001")

key_and_version = [versions['Versions'][0]['Key'], versions['Versions'][0]['VersionId']]

Comment: Sorry to late reply, this though giving me data to identify about key & folder. but for huge data certainly not efficient block. since my case I have versionIds in millions. for most of objects